# How to trigger zoom in and zoom out in plotly chart using user created on click buttons?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, plotly, plotly.js

I am building an angular application. In which we need to create on click buttons for zooming in and zooming out for plotly chart. We can zoom in zoom out in plotly chart using buttons on hoverable mode bar but this is not required for our application. We want to zoom in and zoom out the chart using user created on click buttons. Is there a way to trigger actions of hoverable mode bar zoom in and out using on click buttons? if not then what are the other ways to do? any suggestion is appreciated.

> Code in **.ts** file

```
basicChart() {

    var trace1 = {
        x: ['2020-10-04', '2021-11-04', '2023-12-04'],
        y: [90, 40, 60],
        type: 'scatter'
    };

    var data = [trace1];

    var layout = {
        title: 'Chart',
        showlegend: false
    };

    Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
}
```

Comment: Please add your existing code to give users a place to start.

Comment: @sfarbota  I have added the .ts file code.

Comment: You cannot trigger native Plotly events, but you can provide new X and Y ranges for your chart and apply Plotly.relayout. Can't your users a mouse for zooming in?

Comment: Yes I did it this way only. @Mark

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem and ended up just using the DOM to click the modebar.

#### zoom-functions-example.js

```js
const plot = Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout)
let zoomIn = function(plot){
  plot.querySelector('a[data-attr="zoom"][data-val="in"]').click()
},
let zoomOut = function(plot){
  plot.querySelector('a[data-attr="zoom"][data-val="out"]').click()
},
let resetView = function(plot){
  plot.querySelector('a[data-attr="zoom"][data-val="reset"]').click()
},
```

#### CSS to hide modebar:

```css
.modebar-container{
  display: none;
}
```